# persistent_bottom_nav_bar in flutter disappear

Tags: flutter, dart, navbar

I'm using persistent_bottom_nav_bar package and when I navigate to anew screen from an alertdialog  the navigation bar disappears even when I use

'''

```
PersistentNavBarNavigator.pushNewScreen(
        context,
        screen: doseForm(
          medName: medName,
        )
        withNavBar: true, // OPTIONAL VALUE. True by default.
    pageTransitionAnimation: PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
  );
```

'''